# adding js and css to custom templates

Tags: theming, javascript

i created a custom module, which renderes a custom template.

[i followed this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHTuXXfBs7Y&t=735s)

now basically i want to add, bootstrap, jquery, and some custom stling and scripts,

[I read this article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module),

and i am not able to attach any files to my timplate..

my file structure:

```
 - product_tree
  - templates  
     - products-tree.html.twig
  - src
     - Controller
         - productTreeController.php
  - js
     - bootstrap.min.js
     - customScripts.js
     - ...

  - css
     - customStyles.css
     - bootstrap.min.css
     - ...

  - product_tree.libraries.yml
  - product_tree.info.yml
  - product_tree.module
```

this is my libraries file:

```
# producttree.libraries.yml
product-tree-libraries:
 version: 1.x
  css:
   theme:
    css/customStyles.css: {}
  js:
   js/customScripts.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/jquery
```

this is my hook:

```
function product_tree_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'products_tree' => array(
      'variables' => array('items' => array(), 'title' => '')
    )
  );
}
```

i tried attaching it through the renfer array

```
$build =  array(
    'page' => array (
        '#theme' => 'products_tree',
        '#items' => $items,
        '#title' => 'products', 
        '#attached' => array(
            'library' => array(
              'product_tree/product-tree-libraries',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

and in the twig template:

```
{{ attach_library('product_tree/product-tree-libraries') }}
```

but still no luck,

in the twig i call the css and scripts

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i dont know if that is needed, but i tried with and with out, when i include it, i see in the browser inspector that the css file being uploaded, but then "canceled"

[image]

can any one tell me what should i do? or what am i doing wrong ?

EDIT:
in the controller, I am renderiung the page like this:

```
$items = array(
    array('name' => 'product one'),
    array('name' => 'product two'),
    array('name' => 'product three'),
    array('name' => 'product four')
);  
$build =  array(
    'page' => array (
        '#theme' => 'products_tree',
        '#items' => $items,
        '#title' => 'products', 
    )
);

$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($html);

return $response;
```

i made This according to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/182025/90147)

because i want it to be separated from drupal.
maybe this is the problem?

when i use `BareHtmlPageRenderer` to render the page (according to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/257374/90147)). i see drupal imports and the page looks more alive, but still my custom css and js are not there!

Comment: Indentation looks wrong

Comment: you mean in the libraries file ? i fixed that, thanks

Comment: No it's still wrong. There should be 2 spaces indentation. You only have 1 space indentation. That's why it's not working.

Comment: [Spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534) says number of spaces does not matter in YML, it just needs to be the same number of spaces per block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the Solution for this.. and it is by using the `BareHtmlPageRenderer` (found it [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/257374/90147)) and then attach the files in the controller php file like this

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'product_tree/product-tree-libraries';
```

with out the attachments hook function.

so the controller would look like:

```
    $build =  array(
        'page' => array (
            '#theme' => 'products_tree',
            '#items' => $term_data,
            '#title' => 'products', 
        )
    );

    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'product_tree/product-tree-libraries';



    $attachments = \Drupal::service('html_response.attachments_processor');
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');

    $bareHtmlPageRenderer = new BareHtmlPageRenderer($renderer, $attachments);

    $response = $bareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage($build, 'Page Title', 'markup');
    return $response;
```

it could also be in the `$build` array it self i think.. but this way its better when looking at it..

and still no need for:

```
{{ attach_library('product_tree/product-tree-libraries') }}
```

Or

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the yml indentation:

```
product-tree-libraries:
  version: 1.x
    css:
      theme:
        css/customStyles.css: {}
    js:
      js/customScripts.js: {}
    dependencies:
      core/jquery
```

2. Attach your library with `hook_page_attachments` To attach to hole page.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_page_attachments().
     */
    function product_tree_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
      //- Note YourModuleName/Library name
      $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'product_tree/product-tree-libraries';
    }
```

3. No need for:

```
    {{ attach_library('product_tree/product-tree-libraries') }}
```

Or

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but it still doesnt work! i still cant see my js and css files in the browser,, in the js file i have a console log.. but its not loggint any thing! is there something else you think is wrong?? maybe that i am rendering the page as a seperate template.. (i added some code to the question, its the rendering part in the controller) maybe its the problem ?